# Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse - An AJAX Function that has always worked for me used on a new site is throwing a nasty error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is about a script that I've used for a while now. I have a website where this code still works without any errors (I even copied the code from that project's scripts, because why reinvent the wheel once you've already done it right?), but for some reason now on my new project, I'm getting some very nasty errors! I'd post an image directly on here, but I don't have enough reputation for that it seems. XD https://rellawings.com/error.JPG The important details of what's in the image left are below:

```
Highlighted Above:  var res = JSON.parse(response);

Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    success https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/:2045
    jQuery 6
    <anonymous> https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/:2038
    dispatch jQuery
    h https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/ line 507 > injectedScript:6
    f https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/ line 507 > injectedScript:15
    c https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/ line 507 > injectedScript:6
    c https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/ line 507 > injectedScript:5
    jQuery 8
    <anonymous> https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/:2027
1.01-What-is-Love:2045:28
```

I know that the problem is with this particular line/function: var res = JSON.parse(response);

But this feels so out of left field to suddenly have problems with it while coding my project. It's very strange since it's always worked flawlessly and still does on my other site. This AJAX script is simple and easy to use... at least until you get errors while coding with it in 2022. XD

The jQuery version used is the same as my other site. The only difference is that I'm not including jQuery UI, which frankly should not make a difference, right? The newest version is commented out, because I've tried switching them. But that doesn't change anything that I can see.

This is included in the header html script.

```
<!---<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here's the 'problematic' AJAX script that's always worked for me:

```
<script>
$("#postbtn").click(function(event){
    var b_id = "'.$b_id.'";
    var c_id = "'.$c_id.'";
    var parent = "0";
    var message = $("#commentsbox").html();

    console.log("Book ID: '.$b_id.'");
    console.log("Chapter ID: '.$c_id.'");
    console.log("Is A Child?: " + parent);
    console.log("MSG: " + message);

    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "post-comment.php",
        data: {b_id: b_id, c_id: c_id, parent: parent, message: message},
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            var res = JSON.parse(response);
            if (res.return === "1") {
                $("#allcomments").html(res.contentrefresh);
            } else {
                $("#errorbox").html("There was a problem and your comment could not be posted.").show().delay(8000).fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

And lastly, here's the AJAX PHP script. I'm not 100% sure it's error-free, but I can't get any response from the AJAX under the circumstances.

With this, I'm experimenting to see if I can feed back html formatted content to refresh the comments on the page. If so, I can implement a refresh button that does the same thing, just updating the divs. I've reduced the shared code because if I put up everything that generates comments (and shouldn't be relevant to resolving this issue), this request for help would be longer than necessary.

```
<?php
include "dbcon.php"; include "functions.php"; session_start();

if($_SESSION['theme'] == "dark"){
    $bordercolor = "#DEDEDE";
}
if($_SESSION['theme'] == "light"){
    $bordercolor = "#000000";
}
if($_SESSION['theme'] == "sepia"){
    $bordercolor = "#5F4B32";
}

$commentsQ = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `b_id` = '$b_id' && `c_id` = '$c_id' && `parent` = '0' ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(`upvote` - `downvote`,'0'), `updated`) DESC LIMIT 10";
$commentsR = $conn->query($commentsQ);       
$commentsnum = $commentsR->num_rows;

$contentrefresh = '';

while($comment = $commentsR->fetch_assoc()){
    $likes = $comment[upvote] - $comment[downvote];
    if($likes == 0){
        $likes = "";
    }else{
        $likes = " · '.$likes.' Upvotes";
    }
    $time = date('m/d/y',$comment['updated']);
    $contentrefresh .= '
        <div style="width:98%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
            <table style="width:100%;min-height:160px;">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3" valign="top" align="center" width="75px" style="max-width:80px;min-height:160px;padding-right:15px;">
                        <img src="https://rellawings.com/avatars/'.$comment[uiden].'/'.$comment[avatar].'" class="avatars" title="'.$comment[uname].'" alt="'.$comment[uname].'" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-size:1.3em;text-align:center;height:50px;" valign="top">
                        <span style="float:left;font-weight:bold;">'.$comment[uname].'</span><span style="float:right;">'.$time.'</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom:15px;font-size:1.3em;line-height: 1.8;height:80%;" valign="top">
                        '.parseemoji($comment[message]).'
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:1.3em;cursor:pointer;">
                        <a id="reply-'.$comment[id].'" title="Reply" alt="Reply">Reply</a>'.$likes.' · <span class="material-icons" style="position:relative;top:4px;">thumb_up</span> · <span class="material-icons" style="position:relative;top:4px;">thumb_down</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
            /* If There Are Any Replies */
                $comments2Q = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `b_id` = '$b_id' && `c_id` = '$c_id' && `parent` > '0' ORDER BY `updated` DESC LIMIT 10";
                $comments2R = $conn->query($comments2Q);
                $comment2 = $comments2R->fetch_assoc();     
                $commentsnum2 = $comments2R->num_rows;

                if($comment['id'] == $comment2['parent']){
                    while($comment2 = $comments2R->fetch_assoc()){
                        $likes = $comment2[upvote] - $comment2[downvote];
                        if($likes == 0){
                            $likes = "";
                        }else{
                            $likes = " · '.$likes.' Upvotes";
                        }
                        $time = date('m/d/y',$comment2['updated']);
                        $body .= '
                            <div style="width:98%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                                <table style="width:100%;min-height:160px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td rowspan="3" valign="top" align="center" width="75px" style="max-width:80px;min-height:160px;padding-right:15px;">
                                            <img src="https://rellawings.com/avatars/'.$comment2[uiden].'/'.$comment2[avatar].'" class="avatars" title="'.$comment2[uname].'" alt="'.$comment2[uname].'" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="font-size:1.3em;text-align:center;height:50px;" valign="top">
                                            <span style="float:left;font-weight:bold;">'.$comment2[uname].'</span><span style="float:right;">'.$time.'</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom:15px;font-size:1.3em;line-height: 1.8;height:80%;" valign="top">
                                            '.parseemoji($comment2[message]).'
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size:1.3em;cursor:pointer;">
                                            <a id="reply-'.$comment2[id].'" title="Reply" alt="Reply">Reply</a>'.$likes.' · <span class="material-icons" style="position:relative;top:4px;">thumb_up</span> · <span class="material-icons" style="position:relative;top:4px;">thumb_down</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>       
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        ';
                    }
                }
    $contentrefresh .= '        
            </table>
        </div>
    ';
}

$b_id = htmlentities(trim($_POST['b_id']), ENT_NOQUOTES);
$c_id = htmlentities(trim($_POST['c_id']), ENT_NOQUOTES);
$parent = htmlentities(trim($_POST['parent']), ENT_NOQUOTES);
$message = htmlentities(trim($_POST['message']), ENT_NOQUOTES);

if(empty($parent)){
    $parent = "0";
}

if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])){

    $uiden = $_SESSION['uiden']; $uname = $_SESSION['uname']; $avatar = $_SESSION['avatar'];
    $posted = time(); $updated = $posted;

    $update = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`b_id`, `c_id`, `parent`, `uiden`, `uname`, `avatar`, `message`, `posted`, `updated`) 
    VALUES ('$b_id', '$c_id', '$parent', '$uiden', '$uname', '$avatar', '$message', '$posted', '$updated')";
    if ($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
        $response = ['return'=>'1', 'contentrefresh'=>$contentrefresh];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        $response = ['return'=>'0', 'contentrefresh'=>$contentrefresh];
        echo json_encode($response);   
    }
}
?>
```

I really hope that I don't have to implement some needlessly complex pure javascript solution to get the job done. What is going on with jQuery and it's lovely simplification of the language?

Comment: image linked is 404

Comment: If `$_SESSION[uname]` isn't set, the above script produces no output. This results in JSON.parse() trying to parse an empty string. (although I get "unexpected end of data" when I do this. Anyway, debugging 101: before parsing, do `console.log("response:", response);`

Comment: Trust me, $_SESSION[uname] is declared upon login.
https://rellawings.com/error.JPG ---- Leave it to Windows Snipping Tool to make the extension uppercase and invalidate a link pointed to .jpg. XD

Comment: You should quote all keys when you set or get data from arrays. So for example, instead of `$_SESSION[uname]`, it should be `$_SESSION['uname']` (unless all your keys are lower case constants?) This can become be an issue if you have display errors turned on and error reporting includes warnings etc since it then would output warnings to the screen before you output the json, thus corrupting it.

Comment: what is `$contentrefresh`?

Comment: You can go directly to my site to see it in 'action' XD
https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/1.01-What-is-Love?/

---- UPDATE --- I've noticed that now my other website is suddenly throwing the same errors. Did they retroactively break JSON.parse(response) for older versions of jQuery for some reason? I don't get it. I coded up a storm, and to have my main project suddenly be crippled by this, I'm tempted to scrap that whole site. It bombed anyhow. T.T

Comment: It is better to debug your code piece by piece. For example, did you try `console.log(response);` to see if anything returned from the server? or did you try to remove the `if(isset($_SESSION[uname])){` and return a test array with `json_ecode`. with these approaches, you can find your bug with your skill.

Comment: @M. Eriksson Fine, I went ahead and updated all the calls to the $_SESSION variables in the AJAX PHP but it doesn't resolve my posted problem. XD I'll even adjust every call where I used the type that has no quotes included soonishly.

Comment: _"Did they retroactively break JSON.parse(response) for older versions of jQuery"_ - JSON.parse() is a native JavaScript method and has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Cyrus Raoufi  I sure did. Erm... but funny thing about that... and I don't get why... when I enter console.log(response); it returns the whole HTML for the page. O.O Any idea why? Why would response contain all this? I never told it to store that.

Comment: @Rellawing, it is possible that your code has more than one issue! in these situations, it's tough to find the bug unless you test it correctly!
Another thing is that `$_SESSION[uname]` won't work because `uname` considered a constant

Comment: Where exactly is the PHP code that generates the output located? In a page with HTML? If you have it on the same page as any HTML, then you need to make sure it's in the top (before any output, like HTML) and also put an `exit;` after your `echo`'s to prevent the page from keep rendering/outputting anything else.

Comment: @M.Eriksson It is being successfully called on. POST
 https://rellawings.com/books/2/Superluminal/1/post-comment.php with a 200 OK response.

Comment: @Rellawing So! please update the question and write this critical notice. Does the server respond to the 404 HTML page? or what?

Comment: I was referring to the contents, not the status code, but I saw that you already answered that.

Comment: @M.Eriksson No worries. What generates the content I want to send back via res.contentrefresh is processed well before what I shared in the AJAX PHP. I can share the whole thing, but frankly, it will be a bit TLDR; XD

Comment: @M.Eriksson I went ahead and put the whole PHP AJAX script, but as I said, it'll be TLDR; XD I haven't tested whether child comments will post like I want yet... but given that I'm not getting any 500 internal server errors on the main php that uses the same code, I'm assuming that whether it works or not, it's not a syntax violation. XD Anyhow, the problem is with var res = JSON.parse(response); and the fact that response has the whole page's worth of html stored in it for some weird reason.

Comment: @CyrusRaoufi Which critical notice were you referring to? Update the code to reflect my changes? Sure, I guess. If that's what you mean.

Comment: _"the problem is with var res = JSON.parse(response); "_ - No, it's not. If you send valid json, that method will work. The issue here is that your endpoint doesn't give you a valid json response. _That's_ the issue you need to solve. `JSON.parse()` has always failed on invalid json data.

Comment: @M.Eriksson AHAHAHAHA! This is hilarious!!! *grins* I can't believe this. *shoots myself*

I got it to stop throwing that error. It's weird... the network said 200 OK and it didn't throw me a 404 error or anything like that.... but... I HAVE A PROPER RESPONSE IN MY CONSOLE.LOG now!

I'm quite happy. I looked hard at something that escaped my notice. The url that I was calling on in the AJAX to reach the php file. XD

Answer (score 2):

This is the first time I've tinkered with .htaccess and doing symlinking. So my site uses fake directories so it doesn't show ugly ?mode=etc etc... But this comes with some caveats. XD I have to link directly to MANY resources. Including AJAX php scripts! LOL! How hilarious! This actually got rid of the error and now I have a response! It'll be up to debugging the AJAX PHP script next. '^^

Thanks for replying! I think our conversation led to my getting a moment of eureka here.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://rellawings.com/post-comment.php",
        data: {b_id: b_id, c_id: c_id, parent: parent, message: message},
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            var res = JSON.parse(response);
            if (res.return === "1") {
                $("#allcomments").html(res.contentrefresh);
            } else {
                $("#errorbox").html("There was a problem and your comment could not be posted.").show().delay(8000).fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });
```